# SQL Server trying to keep non printable characters in string format function

Tags: sql-server, regex

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and SSMS version 17.6. I'm trying to write a function that I can pass a string and a "keep" command to that will be used to generate a regular expression to specify what group of characters I want to keep in the string so everything else will be stripped out. Here's my code so far:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_KeepChars]
    (@String NVARCHAR(MAX),  
     @Keep VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        @MatchExpression NVARCHAR(200),
        @Alpha NVARCHAR(1000) = 'a-zA-Z',
        @Numeric NVARCHAR(1000) = '0-9',            
        @PrintSpecial NVARCHAR(1000) = '!-/' --+ CHAR(33) + '-' + CHAR(47) 
                                       + ':-@' --+ CHAR(58) + '-' + CHAR(64) 
                                       + '[-`' -- + CHAR(91) + '-' + CHAR(96)
                                       + '{-~' --+ CHAR(123) + '-' + CHAR(126)
                                       + 'Ç-■' --+ CHAR(128) + '-' + CHAR(255),
        -- @NonPrintSpecial NVARCHAR(100) = CHAR(1)+'-'+CHAR(31),
        @NonPrintSpecial NVARCHAR(100) = 'CHAR(1)-CHAR(31)',
        @AllSpecial NVARCHAR(100) 

    SET @AllSpecial = @NonPrintSpecial + @PrintSpecial

    SELECT 
        @MatchExpression = CASE LOWER(@Keep)
                              WHEN 'alpha' THEN @Alpha
                              WHEN 'num' THEN @Numeric
                              WHEN 'allspec' THEN @AllSpecial
                              WHEN 'printspec' THEN @PrintSpecial
                              WHEN 'nonprintspec' THEN @NonPrintSpecial
                              WHEN 'alphanum' THEN @Alpha + @Numeric
                              WHEN 'alphaallspec' THEN @Alpha + @AllSpecial
                              WHEN 'alphaprintspec' THEN @Alpha + @PrintSpecial
                              WHEN 'alphanonprintspec' THEN @Alpha + @NonPrintSpecial
                              WHEN 'numallspec' THEN @Numeric + @AllSpecial
                              WHEN 'numprintspec' THEN @Numeric + @PrintSpecial
                              WHEN 'numnonprintspec' THEN @Numeric + @NonPrintSpecial
                              WHEN 'alphanumprintspec' THEN @Alpha + @Numeric + @PrintSpecial
                              WHEN 'alphanumnonprintspec' THEN @Alpha + @Numeric + @NonPrintSpecial
                              ELSE 'INVALID_KEEP_PARAMETER_PASSED'
                           END 

    IF CHARINDEX('INVALID_KEEP_PARAMETER_PASSED',@MatchExpression) > 0
        RETURN 'INVALID_KEEP_PARAMETER_PASSED'

    SET @MatchExpression = '%[^' + @MatchExpression + ']%'

    WHILE PATINDEX(@MatchExpression, @String) > 0
        SET @String = STUFF(@String, PATINDEX(@MatchExpression, @String), 1, '')

    RETURN CONVERT(NVARCHAR,GETDATE()) + '      ' + @String
END
```

The only thing that isn't working is the expression generated for matching the non printable characters and stored in the `@NonPrintSpecial` variable. I can only think of defining it two ways:

```
@NonPrintSpecial NVARCHAR(100) = CHAR(1)+'-'+CHAR(31)
```

and

```
@NonPrintSpecial NVARCHAR(100) = 'CHAR(1)-CHAR(31)'
```

Here's the bit I used to test the function:

```
DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @String2 NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @MatchExpression NVARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
    SET @String = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789!@#$%^&*()_+=-`/*-+.\|]}[{/?''"' + CHAR(10)
    SELECT @String AS 'Original string'
    SELECT 'POS OF CHAR(10) in @String= ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),@String)) AS 'Char(10) Position in original string'

    SELECT @String2 = dbo.fn_KeepChars(@String,'allspec') 
    SELECT @String2 AS 'Modified string'
    SELECT 'POS OF CHAR(10) in modified string= ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),@String2)) AS 'Char(10) Position in modified string'
END
```

If I use this variable definition in my function `@NonPrintSpecial NVARCHAR(100) = CHAR(1)+'-'+CHAR(31)` and then run my test the output shows that only printable special characters remain (good) but the CHAR(10) is stripped out which I want to keep.

If I use this variable definition in the function `@NonPrintSpecial NVARCHAR(100) = 'CHAR(1)-CHAR(31)'` and then run my test the output shows that the CHAR(10) is still stripped out and in addition to the special characters that were there before now the characters

> abchrABCHR123456789

are in the modified string as well.

Can someone help me out with what I need to specify as my `@NonPrintSpecial` variable definition so I can accurately keep non-printable characters (like CHAR(10)) in my `@String` that gets passed in to my function?

Comment: You're saying `nvarchar` but you're delimiting strings like they're `varchar`. There's a big difference between `SELECT '■', N'■';` - try it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I don't understand what exact string I need to add "N" in front of to get this function to work how I want it to. Please elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: You have things like `@PrintSpecial NVARCHAR(1000) = '!-/'` ... try `@PrintSpecial NVARCHAR(1000) = N'!-/'`... that N is important, if you don't want to use it, don't bother using the nvarchar data type or trying to store Unicode characters in it...

Comment: @AaronBertrand, sorry I didn't clarify earlier. The `@PrintSpecial` variable is working how I expect it to. The problem I'm getting is when I use the `@NonPrintSpecial` variable. By using the value in my `@NonPrintSpecial` variable I'm trying to say "keep all non-printable characters", that's where the `CHAR(1)-CHAR(31)` comes in to play, that's the ASCII range of non printable characters I want to keep in my string. But, no matter how I specify the value in `@NonPrintSpecial` my function doesn't keep the non printable characters when I tell it to. Please let me know if that makes sense or not

Comment: Well, `@PrintSpecial` can't possibly be working how you expect. `DECLARE @PrintSpecial NVARCHAR(1000) = 'Ç-■'; SELECT @PrintSpecial;` actually yields `Ç-¦`, not `Ç-■`. Anyway, I don't think you can inject a non-printable character into a `PATINDEX()` expression, and `PATINDEX()` won't know what you mean by `CHAR(8)` (or `CHAR(n)-CHAR(y)`) unless you somehow do this with dynamic SQL, but even then, some of those non-printable characters are just going to impact the formatting of the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out an answer to my problem. Thanks to @AaronBertrand for putting me on the track to figure it out. The problem is that `PATINDEX()` was the part of my function that wouldn't recognize the non printable range I was defining that was being added to the regular expression the function builds. After much playing around with it I tried to add the non printable ASCII characters (CHAR(1) to CHAR(31)) to the `@NonPrintSpecial` variable individually and it worked. I'll admit I don't think this looks good but it does work. I'd be willing to bet that someone more experienced with regular expressions than I am would be able to provide a more elegant answer but this is what I was able to come up with:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_KeepChars]
(@String NVARCHAR(MAX),  
@Keep VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        @MatchExpression NVARCHAR(200),
        @Alpha NVARCHAR(1000) = 'a-zA-Z',
        @Numeric NVARCHAR(1000) = '0-9',            
        @PrintSpecial NVARCHAR(1000) = '!-/' --+ CHAR(33) + '-' + CHAR(47) 
                                       + ':-@' --+ CHAR(58) + '-' + CHAR(64) 
                                       + '[-`' -- + CHAR(91) + '-' + CHAR(96)
                                       + '{-~' --+ CHAR(123) + '-' + CHAR(126)
                                       + 'Ç-■', --+ CHAR(128) + '-' + CHAR(255)
        @NonPrintSpecial NVARCHAR(100) =  CHAR(1) + CHAR(2) + CHAR(3) + CHAR(4) + 
                                          CHAR(5) + CHAR(6) + CHAR(7) + CHAR(8) + 
                                          CHAR(9) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(11) + CHAR(12) + 
                                          CHAR(13) + CHAR(14) + CHAR(15) + CHAR(16) + 
                                          CHAR(17) + CHAR(18) + CHAR(19) + CHAR(20) + 
                                          CHAR(21) + CHAR(22) + CHAR(23) + CHAR(24) + 
                                          CHAR(25) + CHAR(26) + CHAR(27) + CHAR(28) + 
                                          CHAR(29) + CHAR(30) + CHAR(31),
        @AllSpecial NVARCHAR(100) 

    SET @AllSpecial = @PrintSpecial + @NonPrintSpecial

    SELECT 
        @MatchExpression = CASE LOWER(@Keep)
                              WHEN 'alpha' THEN @Alpha
                              WHEN 'num' THEN @Numeric
                              WHEN 'allspec' THEN @AllSpecial
                              WHEN 'printspec' THEN @PrintSpecial
                              WHEN 'nonprintspec' THEN @NonPrintSpecial
                              WHEN 'alphanum' THEN @Alpha + @Numeric
                              WHEN 'alphaallspec' THEN @Alpha + @AllSpecial
                              WHEN 'alphaprintspec' THEN @Alpha + @PrintSpecial
                              WHEN 'alphanonprintspec' THEN @Alpha + @NonPrintSpecial
                              WHEN 'numallspec' THEN @Numeric + @AllSpecial
                              WHEN 'numprintspec' THEN @Numeric + @PrintSpecial
                              WHEN 'numnonprintspec' THEN @Numeric + @NonPrintSpecial
                              WHEN 'alphanumprintspec' THEN @Alpha + @Numeric + @PrintSpecial
                              WHEN 'alphanumnonprintspec' THEN @Alpha + @Numeric + @NonPrintSpecial
                              ELSE 'INVALID_KEEP_PARAMETER_PASSED'
                           END 

    IF CHARINDEX('INVALID_KEEP_PARAMETER_PASSED',@MatchExpression) > 0
        RETURN 'INVALID_KEEP_PARAMETER_PASSED'

    SET @MatchExpression = '%[^' + @MatchExpression + ']%'

    WHILE PATINDEX(@MatchExpression, @String) > 0
        SET @String = STUFF(@String, PATINDEX(@MatchExpression, @String), 1, '')

    RETURN @String
END
```

Now I can run this test and the output shows that the position of the carriage return (CHAR(10)) in the modified string the is 25 instead of 0, meaning that the non printable character I added to the string has been kept.

```
DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @String2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
    SET @String = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789!@#$%^&*()_+=-`/*-+.\|]}[{/?''"' + CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)
    SELECT @String AS 'Original string'
    SELECT 'POS OF CHAR(10) in @String= ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),@String)) AS 'Char(10) Position in original string'

    SELECT @String2 = dbo.fn_KeepChars(@String,'allspec') 
    SELECT @String2 AS 'Modified string'
    SELECT 'POS OF CHAR(10) in modified string= ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),@String2)) AS 'Char(10) Position in modified string'
END
```